# Search results aren't printed in the website, only in the command line

Tags: python, html, django

so I added a new page to my website to search for 'people' items. The thing is, whenever I search for an item, the result shows in my command line but it's not printed in the website, the only thing that is are the tags but with the empty result, like this:
Gender:
Age:
Eye color:
Film:
So the result of the query is not printed out. Why is this happening?

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
import requests


def people(request):
    people = []
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        people_url = 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/'
        
        search_params = {
            'people' : 'name',
            'people' : 'gender',
            'people' : 'age',
            'people' : 'eye_color',
            'q' : request.POST['search']
            
            }

        
        r = requests.get(people_url, params=search_params)
        results = r.json()
        
        if len(results):
            for result in results:
                people_data = {
                'Name' : result['name'],
                'Gender': result['gender'],
                'Age' : result['age'],
                'Eye_Color' : result['eye_color']
            }

            people.append(people_data)  
        
        else:
            message = print("No results found")

        print(people)
     

    context = {
    'people' : people
    }
        
    return render(request,'core/people.html', context)
```

This is the html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ghibli Studio | People</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/people.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class=" header">

    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form action='/people' method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="search">


                <input type="text" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Type character name, gender, age, or eye color">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">

                    <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                </button>

            </div>


        </form>
    </div>

    {% if people %}
    {% for p in people %}
    <div>
        <ul class="result">
            <style>
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
            </style>

            <h4>{{people.Name}}</h4>
            <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
                Gender: {{people.Gender}} <br>
                Age: {{people.Age}}
                <br>Eye color: {{people.Eye_color}}
                <br>Film: {{people.Film}}
            </h5>


        </ul>
        {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of an individual person in your template is `p`, not `people`, so:

```
{% for p in people %}
<div>
    <ul class="result">
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
        </style>

        <h4>{{ p.Name }}</h4>
        <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
            Gender: {{ p.Gender }}<br>
            Age: {{ p.Age }}
            <br>Eye color: {{ p.Eye_color }}
            <br>Film: {{ p.Film }}
        </h5>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works except for the eye color feature, would you happen to know why?

Comment: @user12763792: then likely the field is not `Eye_color`, but `Eye_Color`, `EyeColor`, or something else. Note that PEP-8 advices to use `snake_case` for fields, not `PerlCase` (so all in lowercase separated by underscores).